# What are RDS or reliable datagram sockets

Tags: c++, c, sockets

A quick search on RDS points to the linux man page of reliable datagram sockets
**http://linux.die.net/man/7/rds**

Has anybody used it if yes how are they different from TCP or UDP sockets ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few links:

http://linux.die.net/man/7/rds

> Currently, RDS can be transported over Infiniband, and loopback. RDS over TCP is disabled, but will be re-enabled in the near future.

[[rds-devel] What is RDS and why did we build it ?](https://oss.oracle.com/pipermail/rds-devel/2007-November/000228.html):

> .... is a socket interface - existing UDP apps usual run on RDS with no 
>   modifications or require minimal change.

[RDS Wire Specification 3.1](https://oss.oracle.com/projects/rds/dist/documentation/rds-3.1-spec.html):

> The RDS protocol allows multiple reliable datagram socket operations between two nodes to share a single connection-oriented connection. **Currently supported transports include TCP sockets and IB Verbs Reliable Connected connections**.

In other words, it sounds like a message-oriented stream implemented as UDP over TCP.